# sqlitestatement insertion with default value android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to insert into sqlite which has a default value for on of its column. I'm using SQLiteStatement for this goal. I create my table like below

```
public static void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db, boolean ifNotExists) 
{
    String constraint = ifNotExists? "IF NOT EXISTS ": "";
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + constraint + "\"DBUSER\" (" + 
            "\"BLOCKED\" INTEGER DEFAULT 0 ," + 
            "\"USERNAME\" TEXT," +
            "\"USER_ID\" TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL );");
}
```

And i insert into it like this

```
@Override
protected void bindValues(SQLiteStatement stmt, DBUser entity) {
    stmt.clearBindings();

    Boolean blocked = entity.getBlocked();
    if (blocked != null) {
        stmt.bindLong(1, blocked ? 1L: 0L);
    }

    String username = entity.getUsername();
    if (username != null) {
        stmt.bindString(2, username);
    }

    String userId = entity.getUserId();
    if (userId != null) {
        stmt.bindString(3, userId);
    }
}
```

The question is this, how can i insert an item which has default value on 'blocked' value in this structure?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When your statement (which you have not shown) mentions the `BLOCKED` column, then the default value is not used.

The only way to insert the default value is by using a *different* statement, without the `BLOCKED` column.